# Reactive Extensions memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, system.reactive

I have the following code in a WPF application using Reactive Extensions for .NET:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var leftButtonDown = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(this, "MouseLeftButtonDown");
    var leftButtonUp = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(this, "MouseLeftButtonUp");

    var moveEvents = Observable.FromEvent<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove")
        .SkipUntil(leftButtonDown)
        .SkipUntil(leftButtonUp)
        .Repeat()
        .Select(t => t.EventArgs.GetPosition(this));

    moveEvents.Subscribe(point =>
    {
        textBox1.Text = string.Format(string.Format("X: {0}, Y: {1}", point.X, point.Y));
    });
}
```

Will there be a steady increase of memory while the mouse is moving on this dialog?

Reading the code, I would expect that the moveEvents observable will contain a huge amount of MouseEventArgs after a while? Or is this handled in some smart way I'm unaware of?

Comment: Note that a subscriber only receives new events from after he subscribes, so old events are not kept anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be a steady increase in memory usage - why would there be? The events are basically streamed to the subscriber; they're not being buffered up anywhere.

The point of Rx is that events are *pushed* to the subscriber, who can choose what to do with them. It's not like adding events to a list which is then examined later.

(There are ways of buffering events in Rx, but you're not using them as far as I can tell.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To somewhat answer your question "why would there be?" - I asked because I haven't yet understood how this works. It's not clear to me what happens in the line Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(this, "MouseLeftButtonDown");